# Konjunktiv oder Präsens?

Tags: subjunctive

Wir lernen jetzt Konjuktiv 2. Die Lehrerin hat geschrieben:

> Wenn sie nicht in der Nähe wohnen würde, und immer mal wieder aushelfen würde, wüsste ich gar nicht, was ich tun sollte.

Warum benutzen wir hier den Konjunktiv 2 und nicht Präsens ?

Comment: Meinst Du warum nicht _"... was ich tun soll"_ anstatt? Bitte stelle eine klare Frage, und was genau Dir dabei unklar ist.

Comment: Den Satz der Lehrerin sollte man eigentlich so schreiben: _»Wenn sie nicht in der Nähe wohnen und immer mal wieder aushelfen würde, wüsste ich gar nicht, was ich tun sollte.«_

Comment: Ja, das war auch mein Satz

Comment: Das erste Komma im Satz ist zu viel.

Answer (score 3):

Du meinst sicher den Unterschied zwischen **Konjunktiv** und **Indikativ**. *Präsens* ist eine Zeitform, und es gibt den Konjunktiv auch im Präsens.

> Wenn sie nicht in der Nähe wohnen würde, und immer mal wieder aushelfen würde, wüsste ich gar nicht, was ich tun sollte.

Dieser Satz steht im **Konjunktiv II**, weil es sich bloß um einen *Gedankengang* handelt, was *sein könnte* und nicht um etwas, das wirklich ist oder war.

Derselbe Satz im **Indikativ**, und damit es nicht komisch klingt, ersetze ich *wenn* durch *da*.

> Da sie nicht in der Nähe wohnt, und immer mal wieder aushilft, weiß ich nicht, was ich tun soll.

Jetzt sind das alles *Tatsachen*: Sie wohnt nicht in der Nähe. Sie hilft nicht aus. Ich weiß nicht, was ich tun soll.

Comment: Danke schön für die Antwort !